# I don't know how to fix my grade calculator function

Tags: javascript, function

I just have no idea what I did wrong to get undefined answers logged to my console.

I've tried deleting the && clauses but this didn't seem to help at all; actually it made it worse.

```
function gradeCalculator(grade) {
  if (grade >= 90) {
    console.log ("A"); 
  } else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
    console.log ("B"); 
  } else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
    console.log ("C");
  } else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
    console.log ("D"); 
  } else (grade <= 59) 
    console.log ("F");
  }

  console.log(gradeCalculator(92)); //=> "A"
  console.log(gradeCalculator(84)); //=> "B"
  console.log(gradeCalculator(70)); //=> "C"
  console.log(gradeCalculator(61)); //=> "D"
  console.log(gradeCalculator(43)); //=> "F"
```

I expected the output to log to the console as:

'A'
'B'
'C'
'D'
'F'

But it actually came out as:

'A'
'F'
undefined
'B'
'F'
undefined
'C'
'F'
undefined
'D'
'F'
undefined
'F'
undefined

I would really appreciate any and all help, thank you so much! =)

Comment: You're wanting to `return` the values in your function, not `console.log` them.

Comment: You've got two main problems: your final `else` case should not have a condition (`else { ... }` instead of `else (grade <= 59)`. Next, you don't have a final `}` for `gradeCalculator`. As jmoerdyk said, you should also probably be returning values instead of logging them

Comment: Just to explain the output (disregarding the `else` issue): `console.log(gradeCalculator(92)); //=> "A"` will first call `gradeCalculator(92)`. This will log an A. Next, the function ends without returning anything, so the return value ends up being `undefined`. This means the original statement gets now turned into `console.log(undefined); //=> "A"`, which logs the text `undefined`. It is really important to understand this distinction between a function *returning* a value and *logging* a value.

Comment: Thank you Mike Cluck, and @Chris G, and jmoerdyk ! Your answers were great and helped me fix my code! I just started learning JavaScript so I'm not too great at it yet, and I appreciate the input very much! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function gradeCalculator(grade) {
  if (grade >= 90) {
    console.log("A");
  } else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
    console.log("B");
  } else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
    console.log("C");
  } else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
    console.log("D");
  } else {
    console.log("F");
  }
}

gradeCalculator(92); //=> "A"
gradeCalculator(84); //=> "B"
gradeCalculator(70); //=> "C"
gradeCalculator(61); //=> "D"
gradeCalculator(43); //=> "F"
```

The problems were:

- `else (grade <= 59)` - `else` doesn't take a condition, and this case wasn't wrapped in `{` and `}`
- `console.log(gradeCalculator(92)); //=> "A"` - The function wasn't returning anything, so you were `console.log`'ing an undefined value (since the logging was in the function itself)

Comment: hopefully a grade is not 89.5

Comment: Thank you @epascarello for the info, I've changed the code to reflect this =)

Answer (score 0):

```
function gradeCalculator(grade) {
      if (grade >= 90) {
        console.log ("A"); 
      } else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
        console.log ("B"); 
      } else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
        console.log ("C");
      } else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
        console.log ("D"); 
      } else if(grade <= 59){
        console.log ("F");
      }
    }
```

Your last `else` should be `else if` with a condition.
(You can just put `else` but `else if` with a condition is more maintainable.